# is there a way to stop the istream_iterator when a new line is encountered?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<char> a(n);
    copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin),istream_iterator<char>(),a.begin());
    copy(a.begin(),a.end(),ostream_iterator<char>(cout," "));    
    return 0; 
}
```

in the 7th line, to stop the `istream_iterator` needs to be stopped explicitly by pressing `Ctrl + z`

Else the `istream_iterator` continues to expect input and it is stuck there until the user presses `Ctrl + Z` and then the rest of code is executed

Comment: Sitenote: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Is this question still unanswered? I ask because I thought I answered it. Ask if it's not clear please.

Answer (score 0):

No, and in your case that would be wrong. If you stop at a newline, the user may have entered more than `n` `char`s and then you have undefined behavior since you would write out-of-bounds.

You need [`copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
copy_n(istream_iterator<char>(cin), n, a.begin());
```